# Setting same domain name in a variable not working for multiple location block in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to **resolve DNS every time** when a new request will come,
I am trying to resolve DNS dynamically in Nginx by setting DNS in a variable. It is working correctly for the below example.

```
server {
    location /mypath {
        resolver 10.0.3.2 10.0.2.2 ipv6=off valid=10s;
        resolver_timeout 30s;
        set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers/mypath;
    }
}
```

but when I have multiple Location blocks with the **same DNS name in the variable**, it is not able to resolve the DNS.

```
server {
    location /mypath {
        resolver 10.0.3.2 10.0.2.2 ipv6=off valid=10s;
        resolver_timeout 30s;
        set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers/mypath;
    }
    location /mysecondpath {
        resolver 10.0.3.2 10.0.2.2 ipv6=off valid=10s;
        resolver_timeout 30s;
        set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers/mysecondpath;
    }
}
```

If you observe $backend_servers is used in both location block. if I use any one of them only Nginx proxy works perfectly. when I use both it returns 502.

What I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things why DNS resolver is not working with proxy URLs

1. *DNS Resolver that you are using is might be wrong.* Please confirm with Your 
   infra admin. According to your DNS resolver, I guess your AWS VPC CIDR block is 
   10.0.0.0/16. If it is correct then use 10.0.0.2 As DNS resolver.
2. Also when you are using a dynamic proxy (Proxy through a variable), You need to specify query param as well. The correct syntax that worked for me is as below

   `server {
       location /mypath/(.*) {
           resolver 10.0.0.2 ipv6=off valid=10s;
           resolver_timeout 30s;
           set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
           proxy_pass http://$backend_servers/mypath/$1$is_args$args;
       }
       location /mysecondpath/(.*) {
           resolver 10.0.0.2 ipv6=off valid=10s;
           resolver_timeout 30s;
           set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
           proxy_pass http://$backend_servers/mysecondpath/;
       }
   }`

Comment: You are correct, I just confirmed, CIDR block of my VPC is 10.0.0.0/16 but unfortunately not able to resolve by 10.0.0.2

Comment: are you working on which environment, aws or local? It will not resolve DNS on local so it will not work on that.